# Segmentation error occurred while creating and trans versing a doubly linked list

Tags: c, pointers

i was creating a double linked and it was showing unexpected behaiviour ,it is not printing the data stored in linked list.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITEXi.png)

is something wrong in my logic?
also do i need to allocate dyamic memory for temp , head and tail node?
because since when i was creating a single linked list , i just used malloc() on new_node only . and it worked wonderfully.

and in double linked list code.
if i dont use malloc() on head ,tail
segmentation error occurs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/03V0j.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{
int value,ch;
struct node{
int data;
struct node *next;
struct node *prev;
}*new_node,*head,*tail,*temp;

head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
node*));
tail=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
node*));  
temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
node*));  

do{
new_node=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
node*));

printf("Hello user , enter data for your 
node\n");
scanf("%d" , &value);
new_node->data=value;
if(head==NULL)
{
new_node->next=NULL;
new_node->prev=NULL;
head=new_node;
tail=new_node;

}
else
{
new_node->prev=tail;
new_node->next=NULL;
tail->next=new_node;
tail=new_node;
}


printf("\ndo you want to add extra node? 
\nenter 0 to continiue or 1 for exit\n");

scanf("%d",&ch);


}while(ch==0);


temp=head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
printf("%d", temp->data);
temp=temp->next;
}

printf("\nprogram executed");

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Please indent and format your code properly. It's not only for machines to read.

Comment: @SAMRAT PATEL  Such memory allocation head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
node*)); is incorrect. You need to allocate memory for an object of the type struct node instead of allocating memory for a pointer So you need to write head=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct 
node));

Comment: You have `head = malloc(...)` follow by `head = new_node`. What do you think happens with those assignments? What happens with the pointer that was returned by `malloc`? Same with `tail` and `temp`.

Comment: @SAMRAT PATEL Also your code produces memory leaks.

Comment: Also, after `head = malloc(...)`, and the `malloc` call doesn't fail, will `head` ever be equal to `NULL`? This is the likely root cause of your crash. I think you might need to take a few steps back, and refresh your knowledge on pointers and how they work.

Comment: Have you drawn this out on a blank piece of paper? Then done that again. Then again? This code is all-over-the-place when it comes to implementing a circular linked list. Less typing, more drawing and thinking and planning.

Comment: Also (and I wonder why nobody hasn't commented about that): don't post pictures of text, post text as properly formatted text. Input and output is text.